# Change X axis date range start point depending on user selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

So for the purposes of this quandry, I have two tables in Power BI desktop. A '**Finance**' and a '**Calendar**' table.

The Calendar table has a filter (towards) relationship with 'Finance.' They are joined on **Finance[Transaction date]** = **Calendar[date]**.

Finance contains transactions from individuals, there might be multiple for each individual.

I want to know how I can display a count of transactions by year for a selected individual (or individuals) from the 'Finance' table on a bar graph axis in a way that the dates start at the point of their first transaction, rather than the first date in the calendar table.

I'm open to changing the model, so any way of achieving this independent of my current setup is welcome. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure this is what you are looking ,

If you want to show numbers on your whatever visualization you can add it from here

[image]

it displays numbers accordingly